# How to embedd multiple videos in a youtube player

Tags: jquery, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to create a simple youtube player that should show thumbnail of videos and should play them consecutively. I know youtube instant does this but the JS is minified so I can't make much sense of it. 
I'm not looking for a premade playlist that can be embedded into a player, because eventually I want to be able to add more videos through an ajax load. For now I am simply trying to have a player that can play two videos.

This is what I have so far:  http://jsfiddle.net/V2nJG/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of player parameters that you can pass to YouTube: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html

> **playlist**
>
> Value is a comma-separated list of video IDs to play. If you
> specify a value, the first video that plays will be the VIDEO_ID
> specified in the URL path, and the videos specified in the playlist
> parameter will play thereafter.

The link above is to the general YouTube documentation area, check-out the JavaScript API links (they will be very useful for learning how to interact with the player).

Also, using an `<iframe>` embed is easier and puts more of the hassle on YouTube's shoulders. For instance YouTube will decide how to output the video based on the device it's playing on.

Your embed code can be this simple:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

*Source: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html*

Comment: @Mike Here is a demo of creating a playlist with an iframe embed: http://jsfiddle.net/Zc6Ng/. BTW, an iframe embed can do everything that an old-school one can do.

Comment: ah thats much better thank you! I could not find but do you know if its possible to append more id's to the comma separated playlist through ajax and have them be queued instantly instead of refreshing the page. Thanks again

Comment: That's what the JavaScript API is for: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html. Look through all the functions you can run, there are several ways to update a playlist.